# Is there an SQLite equivalent to MySQL's DESCRIBE [table]?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-schema, dbtable

I'm just getting started learning [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). It would be nice to be able to see the details for a table, like MySQL's `DESCRIBE [table]`. `PRAGMA table_info [table]` isn't good enough, as it only has basic information (for example, it doesn't show if a column is a field of some sort or not). Does SQLite have a way to do this?

Answer (score 612, accepted):

The [SQLite command line utility](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) has a `.schema TABLENAME` command that shows you the create statements.

Comment: You can use ".schema" without a table and it'll show you all of them.

Comment: Don't forget to leave out the semi-colon at the end of the statement

Comment: A semi-colon is not required

Comment: @Simon a semi-colon will cause the command to silently *fail*.

Comment: @djeikyb. shouldn't this be considered a bug?

Comment: Possibly they fixed this, since at least in my version of SQLite (3.8.10.2), I can issue `.schema` and `.schema users` (for example) and the output seems to be correct---no semicolon needed for me.

Comment: Note that `.schema` is a command for the `sqlite3`-shell and **NOT** valid SQL. Meaning if you want to get the table-info in an application, you have to use **@Strater**'s answer.

Comment: Typing ".help " can  help in finding useful commands like ".shema"

Comment: Even though the OP said, "PRAGMA table_info [table] isn't good enough, as it only has basic information"?

Answer (score 342):

```
PRAGMA table_info([tablename]);
```

Comment: This seems more equivalent to MySQL's describe than `.schema tablename` to me.

Comment: Yep. This worked for me. .schema TABLENAME didn't. .schema alone, however, does show you all the create statements, but the result from PRAGMA is a lot more useful if I just want to look at one table.

Comment: This seems like it should be the accepted answer since it works through querying instead of being dependent on a command line interface. +1 from me.

Comment: Addendum: The only thing I'm noticing is that it does not output PRIMARY KEY when I create a table with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, just INTEGER.

Comment: @AkoiMeexx: From my original question: "`PRAGMA table_info [table]` isn't good enough, as it only has basic information (for example, it doesn't show if a column is a field of some sort or not)."

Comment: It also displays the data in a more table like format rather than looking at the CREATE statement from the .schema command

Answer (score 131):

Are you looking for the SQL used to generate a table?  For that, you can [query the `sqlite_schema` table](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT, quux TEXT);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_schema;
table|foo|foo|2|CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT, quux TEXT)
sqlite> SELECT sql FROM sqlite_schema WHERE name = 'foo';
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT, quux TEXT)
```

> ###### [Alternative Names](https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html#alternative_names)
>
> The schema table can always be referenced using the name `sqlite_schema`, especially if qualifed by the schema name like `main.sqlite_schema` or `temp.sqlite_schema`. But for historical compatibility, some alternative names are also recognized, including:
>
> 1. `sqlite_master`
> 2. `sqlite_temp_schema`
> 3. `sqlite_temp_master`
>
> Alternatives (2) and (3) only work for the TEMP database associated with each database connection, but alternative (1) works anywhere.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and `.schema foo`?

Comment: @Matthew: `.schema` can only be used from a command line; the above commands can be run as a query through a library (Python, C#, etc.).

Comment: @MarkRushakoff But the result is the same?

Comment: +1 "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master" works in chrome dev tools when debugging WebSql

Answer (score 61):

To see all tables:

```
.tables
```

To see a particular table:

```
.schema [tablename]
```

Comment: Giving table name inside [square bracket] doesn't work. You have to give `.schema TABLENAME`

Comment: @PayelSenapati The brackets are just to indicate that `tablename` is an optional parameter.

Answer (score 9):

To prevent that people are mislead by some of the comments to the other answers:

1. If `.schema` or `query from sqlite_master` not gives any output, it indicates a non-existent `tablename`, e.g. this may also be caused by a `;` semicolon at the end for `.schema`,  `.tables`, ... Or just because the table really not exists.
   That `.schema` just doesn't work is very unlikely and then a bug report should be filed at the sqlite project.

> ... .schema can only be used from a command line; the above commands > can be run as a query through a library (Python, C#, etc.). –  Mark Rushakoff Jul 25 '10 at 21:09

2. 'can only be used from a command line' may mislead people. Almost any (likely every?) programming language can call other programs/commands. Therefore the quoted comment is unlucky as calling another program, in this case `sqlite`, is more likely to be supported than that the language provides a `wrapper`/`library` for every program (which not only is prone to incompleteness by the very nature of the masses of programs out there, but also is counter acting `single-source principle`, complicating `maintenance`, furthering the chaos of data in the world).

Comment: Anybody writing a program to retrieve data from any SQL database should use the proper SQL drivers available to their programming language for accessing the database and performing queries on it. That is the appropriate way to access a database. I would never recommend hacking a command-line program designed to provide ad-hoc queries. Your suggestion is deeply mistaken. A command-line program for ad-hoc queries is CERTAINLY NOT the most appropriate access point for program code to run queries on a database. Using SQL drivers is CERTAINLY NOT 'complicating maintenance' - it is best practice.

Comment: I agree it is no bad, it is similar to libraries. Which is why Linux|BSD distros ship package managers. And why there is 0install cross platform PM.

My point was just to clarify that not all programs need wrappers. It does not make sense everytime. In this case (DB handling) of course it not a bad idea to use a wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

**".schema"** can show **more details of tables including *Table Constraints*** than **"PRAGMA"**.

This command below shows **the details of all tables**:

```
.schema
```

This command below shows **the details of all tables in a well-formatted way**:

```
.schema --indent
```

This command below shows **the details of one table**:

```
.schema <table_name>
```

These commands below show **the details of one table in a well-formatted way**:

```
.schema --indent <table_name>
```

Or:

```
.schema <table_name> --indent
```

In addition, these commands below show **the details about ".schema"**:

```
.help .schema
```

Or:

```
.help schema
```

Then, this is how it looks like below:

```
sqlite> .help .schema 
.schema ?PATTERN?        Show the CREATE statements matching PATTERN
   Options:
      --indent             Try to pretty-print the schema
      --nosys              Omit objects whose names start with "sqlite_"
```

Answer (score 2):

***If***  you're using a graphical tool. It shows you the schema right next to the table name. In case of ***DB Browser For Sqlite***, click to open the database(top right corner), navigate and open your database, you'll see the information populated in the table as below.

[image]

> right click on the record/table_name, click on **copy create statement** and there you have it.

Hope it helped some beginner who failed to work with the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have these tables in my Django SQLite database:

```bash
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
```

Then

```bash
.tables
```

In order to describe and see the SQL statements for shop_product table, you can run the following command:

```bash
.schema shop_product
```

#### Illustration

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

`.schema user_meta` didn't work for me.
but `.schema` did show me all the tables.

I was able to see user_meta table using this command:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='user_meta';
table|user_meta|user_meta|7|CREATE TABLE user_meta (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(10), 
    last_name VARCHAR(10), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id), 
    UNIQUE (user_id)
)
```