# Why am I getting a syntax error in python (sqlite3)?

Tags: python, sqlite

Why am I getting a syntax error with the following line?

```
statement = self.sql.execute("DESCRIBE TEST")
```

I get the following error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DESCRIBE": syntax error

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330435/is-there-a-sqlite-equivalent-to-mysqls-describe-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` is not a valid sqlite3 command, use `.schema TEST`

Comment: If I do statement = self.sql.execute(".schema TEST") I get: "OperationalError: near ".": syntax error"

Comment: that only works on the sqlite shell I believe