# Table description in Sqlite expert database

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to get the table description in **Sqlite Expert Professional**? I tried:

```
Desc Table_name
exec sp_help Table_name
sp_columns Table_name
sp_help Table_name
Execute sp_help Table_name
```

All commands return nothing, except of an error message. What is the correct command?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330435/is-there-a-sqlite-equivalent-to-mysqls-describe-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think SQLite hates me - so instead of the query being

`PRAGMA table_info('member');`

I now used

`SELECT * FROM member WHERE 1 = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

PRAGMA table_info(Table_name);