# obtain query result using sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 for accessing database. I want to know the number of rows, the number of columns, and the name of the column from the queried result and database.

For example if I run `SELECT * from table`, and I get

```
id    name    number
--------------------
1     John    10
2     Jay     20
```

How can I know that the database has 2 rows, and 3 columns, and the number of columns are id/name/number?

Comment: You better know your table structure right from the beginning. And you can get the number of rows from your resultset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Sqlite equivalent to MySQL's DESCRIBE \[table\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330435/is-there-a-sqlite-equivalent-to-mysqls-describe-table)

Answer (score 0):

Asking "how many cols" is the wrong question, because you normally "know" what data you are interested in.

You can count the number of rows using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

The result will look like this:

```
COUNT(*)
---------
2
```

If you want a nicer display, use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM table;
```

returning:

```
rows
-----
2
```