# generating random value in Sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to pick one customer each month from the three countries, Germany, Canada, Brazil (table name Country). I need to generate their first , last name and their ID which is in another table called "customer". I had this idea to start of with but wasn't 100% if I was on right track.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountryID
FROM Country
WHERE CountryName IN('Germany','Canada','Brazil')


Country ID  CountryName
"1"         "Brazil"
"2"         "Germany"
"3"         "Canada"
"4"         "Norway"
"5"         "Czech Republic"
"6"         "Austria"
"7"         "Belgium"
```

The customer table

```
"0" "CustomerId"    "INTEGER"   "1" "NULL"  "1"
"1" "FirstName" "VARCHAR(40)"   "1" "NULL"  "0"
"2" "LastName"  "VARCHAR(20)"   "1" "NULL"  "0"
"3" "Company"   "VARCHAR(80)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"4" "Address"   "VARCHAR(70)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"5" "City"  "VARCHAR(40)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"6" "State" "VARCHAR(40)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"7" "Country"   "VARCHAR(40)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"8" "PostalCode"    "VARCHAR(10)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"9" "Phone" "VARCHAR(24)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"10" "Fax"  "VARCHAR(24)"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
"11""Email" "VARCHAR(60)"   "1" "NULL"  "0"
"12""SupportRepId"  "INTEGER"   "0" "NULL"  "0"
```

Comment: Ok so you want to obtain the first name, last name, and id of someone in table `customer`, and you want to pick them randomly from table customer. So why do we need table `Country`? is there a column called `Country` in the Customer table? please elaborate, and it would be nice to see table `customer`

Comment: yeah i just realised that was silly of me. There is a table in Customer called Country

Comment: But how would i randomly generate just one ? and also get all those other values

Comment: Would me answering how to generate a random number in SQL suffice?

Comment: I'm just unsure how to approach it

Comment: To get the random country "each month" and then generate their first last name an customer ID

Comment: @M.Jones Doesn't the `RAND()` function do what you want?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite? Why do you have both tags?

Comment: Using SQLite, when I use RAND() function , how do i get a customer from each month without having a month table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RAND()` function generates a random number. You can use it in `ORDER BY` to select a random rows matching some criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, CustomerId
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Country = 'Brazil'
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 1
    ) 
UNION
    (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, CustomerId
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Country = 'Germany'
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 1
    ) 
UNION
    (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, CustomerId
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Country = 'Canada'
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 1
    )
)
```

Comment: will this pick a customer each month  ?

Comment: I don't understand why you started of with cus.*

Comment: Because you just want the customer information, not the information from the `Country` table as well.

Comment: @M.Jones You can use a cron job to run it every month.

Comment: how would i get one customer each month though ? , yeah sorry i just got bit confused with the names you used

Comment: Do you mean there's a date column in one of the tables, and you need to group the results by month? It would help if you posted your schema, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: its hard because its such a big database. There is no date column or anything to do with dates in the database.

Comment: I tried doing this SELECT FirstName, LastName, CustomerId
FROM Customer 
JOIN Country AS c ON Country = CountryId
WHERE CountryName = 'Brazil'
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1                           But it came up with no results

Comment: Do you get anything if you leave out `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Comment: Nope it still remains blank

Comment: Then you don't have any customers in Brazil.

Comment: I do I've tried other country names aswell doesn't seem to work

Comment: Make a sqlfiddle with sample data.

Comment: Not sure how to create the sqlfiddle, I'm just trying to figure out whats wrong at the moment

Comment: Go to www.sqlfiddle.com, paste in the statements to create and populate the tables.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, too. But I can't do it without sample data.

Comment: The tables were already created when i imported the database, how do i copy those ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330435/is-there-a-sqlite-equivalent-to-mysqls-describe-table

Comment: I put the customer headings in my code above i edited it in

Comment: The `Country` column in `Customer` should be `INTEGER`, not `VARCHAR`. It should be the ID from the `Country` table.

Comment: Since you put the country name in the `Customer` table instead of the ID, there's no need to join with the `Country` table at all.

Comment: okay i see , and if you were to make it 3 random countries would you simply go WHERE Country = 'Brazil', AND "Germany" AND "Canada" Limit 3

Comment: No, that won't work. When you use `AND`, a row has to satisfy all the conditions, and no single row can have 3 different countries. You need to do a separate query for each country. You can combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: You also can't change it to `OR`. That will find customers from all 3 countries, but the random 3 that are selected won't necessarily be from different countries -- you could get all 3 from Brazil.

Comment: okay thanks ! I'll get onto that and then try do it so its chosen every month

Comment: I managed to do it using IN operator and it works fine. Just need to do the dates, which seems bit harder

Comment: @M.Jones That's the same as `OR`. It won't get one customer from each country. It will get 3 customers from all 3 countries.

Comment: I changed the Limit to 1 so it only gets one random

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to find a way to have it pick one customer from every month without creating the month table.

Comment: You're not making sense. How can it pick a customer from a month if there's no month in the table.

Comment: What month are you talking about? The month that the customer was created, the month that they made a purchase? If the latter, you need to join with the purchase table.

Comment: so I need to create a column in customer called month ?

Comment: Or a column called `CreatedDate`, and then use `MONTH(CreatedDate)` to get the month.